# Command line piping four commands

Tags: python, command-line

I'm doing two python scripts that was to work with other two programs given by the professor of the subject.

The programs work on this order:

```
fonte -> newCodificador -> canal -> newDescodificador
```

The program named `fonte` and `canal` are made by the professor, the other ones are mine.

The problem is to **run the program in the terminal the outputs of the program are passed by pipes | to the final one**. I need before passing the output of the program `newCodificador` to `canal` to read the length of the output and then pass as an argument of the program.

It has to be something like this:

```
./fonte 1000 | python newCodificador.py | ./canal <<lenght of the output of newCodificador>> | python newDescodificador.py
```

Comment: I can't imagine what you think this has to do with makefiles.

Comment: You said the problem is to execute the four commands (with args), piping the results. This is just a little scripting, why do think using Makefile adds anything, you can equally use the UNIX shell? Do you need to parameterize the executable names?

Comment: The only argument is the "1000" value that is given by the user,  the rest is program made but i need to pass the length of the output of the python newCodificador.py as an argument of ./canal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make is not useful for this problem, as you've described it.

Second, you cannot solve this problem using a single pipeline. A pipeline works by invoking all the programs at the same time, with their input/output hooked together.  But you cannot start the `canal` program until after the `newCodificador.py` program completes, because until that happens you don't know how long the output will be.

You *must* run these in two steps: the first step would be:

```
./fonte 1000 | python newCodificador.py > tmpfile
```

then the second step would be:

```
./canal $(wc -c tmpfile) < tmpfile | python newDescodificador.py
```

Or something like that.

Comment: I tried it the problem is that the wc -c output is << length of file >> tmpfile

Comment: It's pretty crap command-line design by the professor to have `nC.py | ./canal <<length of output of nC.py>>`. `canal` should read and compute its input length, internally. That makes everything chainable in a single pipe like @MadScientist says.

Comment: Yap i know, but i can't do nothing, i can't edit the code the professor gave to me.

Comment: Well, this is a homework assignment, right?  You should be willing to do some of the work :).  There are a ton of ways to deal with this: pipe the output of `wc` through sed to get just the first word; or use the `stat` program instead of `wc` to print just the file size; have `newCodificador.py` compute the size and print it out, and capture it by running the first pipeline in backticks; and more options.

Comment: I have manage to solve my problem thanks to you, MadScientist, i have edited a little bit your code to make it work, just . /canal $(cat tmpfile |wc -c) < tmpfile | python newDescodificador.py, thanks to all of the help !

Comment: That's a UUOC; you could write `./canal $(wc -c <tmpfile) <tmpfile`.  Glad it worked for you!